# Angular project not working after installation of newer version of node.js

Tags: node.js, angular7

I am working with an angular 7 project.
initially, I was using node version 10 and by mistake, I upgrade the node to version 12.

after that, I tried to compile my Angular 7 project it is the thrwing error. I again reinstall the older version but still, it is throwing the error as below.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/pages/pages.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.sassLoader (E:\QiwkCollaborator\QiwkCollaboratorTool\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:72)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ionicons/scss/ionicons.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./node_modules/ionicons/scss/ionicons.scss)
```

I don't have any idea how to resolve this error. any suggestions, please.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You'll need to upgrade node-sass at the very least--it's sensitive to NodeJS versions.

Answer (score 0):

Currently having same issue, solution I am implementing is to use docker to run the older version of node that is compatible with the node-sass or install a newer version of the package.